# Xcode 7.1 Errors UIAccessibility Errors

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uiaccessibility

I finally got around to it and updated Xcode to 7.1.  But now I am getting all these warnings in the debugger.  My app uses no UIWebViews.  I use Parse as a backend, but this is the first time I've been presented with these issues.  Any one with any ideas how to fix this?  Would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
UIAccessibility Error adding -[DOMNode _moveRight:withHistory:]
UIAccessibility Error adding -[DOMNode _moveLeft:withHistory:]
UIAccessibility Error adding -[DOMNode _updateSelectionWithTextRange:withAffinityDownstream:]
UIAccessibility Error adding +[DOMNode safeCategoryBaseClass]
UIAccessibility Error adding -[UIWebFormAccessory _accessibilityLoadAccessibilityInformation]
UIAccessibility Error adding -[UIWebFormAccessory initWithFrame:]
UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebFormAccessory safeCategoryBaseClass]
UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebFormSelectPeripheral safeCategoryBaseClass]
UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebFormSelectPeripheral createPeripheralWithDOMHTMLSelectElement:]
UIAccessibility Error adding -[UIWebSelectSinglePicker _accessibilityServesAsFirstElement]
UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebSelectSinglePicker safeCategoryBaseClass]
UIAccessibility Error adding -[UIWebSelectMultiplePicker _accessibilityServesAsFirstElement]
UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebSelectMultiplePicker safeCategoryBaseClass]
UIAccessibility Error adding -[UIWebPlugInView webPlugInStart]
UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebPlugInView safeCategoryBaseClass]
```

Comment: Xcode 7.2.1, iOS 9.2.1, ARC enabled.  This happens to me as well.  It seems to be intermittent and I tried restarting my phone, the issue comes back from time to time.  Happens only on an actual device.  Any update on this?

Comment: Happens in my simulator iPhone 6s Plus

Comment: Happens when we are using KIF https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF to execute tests in the simulators for iPhone 6 and iPad Air 2. Xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why this error happened, but restarting device solved my problem.

Comment: Rebooted the iOS simulator and it worked for me as well. Anyone knows the reason?